# Error using gdalwarp

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, gdalwarp, linux

I have this NetCDF file of the Greenland ice sheet velocities but the coordinate system is NSIDC Sea Ice Polar Stereographic North (y: -655750 to -3355750 and x: -639750 to 855750 meters). I wanted to project these data to WGS84 lat/lon degrees but got the following error:

```
gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70
+lon_0=-45 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs EPSG:4326 lgreenland_vel_cci.nc greenland_latlon.nc

Warning: The target file has a 'nc' extension, which is normally used by the GMT, netCDF drivers, but the requested output driver is GTiff. Is it really what you want? 
ERROR 1: Input file lgreenland_vel_cci.nc has no raster bands.
```

For the ones interested, here is some info about the netcdf (it can also be downloaded from the site of the CCI http://products.esa-icesheets-cci.org/products/downloadlist/IV/):

```
Variables:
    crs                                
           Size:       1x1
           Dimensions: 
           Datatype:   int32
           Attributes:
                       grid_mapping_name                     = 'polar_stereographic'
                       standard_parallel                     = 70
                       straight_vertical_longitude_from_pole = -45
                       false_easting                         = 0
                       false_northing                        = 0
                       unit                                  = 'meter'
                       latitude_of_projection_origin         = 90
                       spatial_ref                           = 'PROJCS["WGS 84 / NSIDC Sea Ice Polar Stereographic North",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Polar_Stereographic"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",70],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-45],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3413"]]'
    y                                  
           Size:       5401x1
           Dimensions: y
           Datatype:   double
           Attributes:
                       units         = 'm'
                       axis          = 'Y'
                       long_name     = 'y coordinate of projection'
                       standard_name = 'projection_y_coordinate'
    x                                  
           Size:       2992x1
           Dimensions: x
           Datatype:   double
           Attributes:
                       units         = 'm'
                       axis          = 'X'
                       long_name     = 'x coordinate of projection'
                       standard_name = 'projection_x_coordinate'
land_ice_surface_velocity_magnitude
       Size:       2992x5401
       Dimensions: x,y
       Datatype:   single
       Attributes:
                   _FillValue   = 3.402823466385289e+38
                   units        = 'meter day-1'
                   description  = 'magnitude of horizontal ice velocity'
                   grid_mapping = 'crs'
                   coordinates  = 'y x'
```

Comment: The reason for the first error is that you did not tell the desired format so the default that is GeoTIFF was used. Try with `-of netCDF`. https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#gdalwarp and  https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/netcdf.html#raster-netcdf. The other error seems to mean that your netCDF does not contain rasters but vector data https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/netcdf.html. Then the right tool for conversion is ogr2ogr.

Answer (score 1):

We can do one error at a time:

> Warning: The target file has a 'nc' extension, which is normally used by the GMT, netCDF drivers, but the requested output driver is GTiff. Is it really what you want?

If you don't want a geotiff output, which is the default. You need to set a format so add:

`-of GMT`

It might be a vector file as well as suggested in the comments.

Try ogr2ogr:

`ogr2ogr -f netCDF -s_srs "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70
+lon_0=-45 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs EPSG:4326 greenland_latlon.nc lgreenland_vel_cci.nc`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply. I tried adding the -of in the command line, now that is gone but still gives the other error. This is from gdalinfo:

Comment: Try ogr2ogr as suggested in the comments.

Comment: This worked fine: gdalwarp -overwrite -of netCDF -s_srs "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=-45 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs EPSG:4326 NETCDF:"lgreenland_vel_cci.nc":land_ice_surface_velocity_magnitude greenland_latlon.nc